# SQL Server query to get the difference between two dates in two different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to write a SQL Server query which should get the difference between two dates (i.e. dates are available in two columns named "Start date" and "End date"). I would like to find the difference between two dates in these two different columns and update in another column as "Expired" if the difference is -1 or below. Most importantly: The time should start from the specified start date and it should check periodically.

Comment: Term expired sounds like it is related to current time and not to start time. Are you sure your requirements are ok? Also, I wouldn't add any logic for updating that, you can just add a determination for it into the select clause you're using

Comment: Well, you haven't posted what you're tried yet. Start with [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: What do you mean by "it should check periodically."?  Are you saying you want to run a scheduled job with this update query as the job itself, for example?

Comment: @JamesZ Oh I am sorry I should have been clear. What I am looking for is something similar to this: I am wondering if there is any way for starting the time dynamically in the "DateTime" field in SQL Server. I have a column named "Start date" which looks in the format like "2015-06-11 00:00:00.000". I would need to start the time at this specific date from 12.00 AM exactly and keep running until the end_date. Once the difference becomes "0" or below, it should update a column as "Expired". Is there any way of starting the timer dynamically using SQL query?

Comment: @MattCampbell Yes, you got me. You are perfectly right. Could you please help me out?

Comment: @Harish Sounds like you'd need to create a query that is executed at specific times or at intervals using the SQL Server Agent.  As for the query itself, I think you have the answer you need below (ie., it's been addressed by others).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATEDIFF](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp) and `case when` like this:

```
update table set expColumn = case when DATEDIFF(day,start_date,end_date) > 0 
       then 'Expired' end FROM table
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To find the differential between two date values you use the DATEDIFF() function.

Also, depending on your requirements, you can set this up in your table as a Computed Column.  That way any changes to the component columns in the computed column's definition will automatically update the computed column to reflect the new values.
With the PERSISTED keyword you can also allow the computed column to be indexed on.
Check the documentation here for more details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is based on what I think you are trying to do, it's not exactly clear.

I don't think you want to add a column to your table to identify what is expired because that column would be dependant on the "End Date" column as well as the primary key which would violate the 3rd normal form. It really shouldn't be needed because you can query out which ones are expired at any time. I can't really think of a scenario where you would need to have a column that indicates expiry. You can create a query like others mentioned to display (not create) another column that marks the expired rows, or you can simply display only the ones expired, or it might make more sense to move them to a different table.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ExpiredTableName ON 

INSERT INTO ExpiredTableName (Column1, Column2, StartDate, EndDate)
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, InvoiceDate, '2015-04-20') >0
```

Identity Insert is for auto-generated keys only.

You can run your queries at regular time intervals like was already mentioned.